# Strange behavior of Ruby on Rails Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am a Ruby newbie and I have been struggling with the following routing problem:

I have a Publishers controller in my app, and I want to use it as a singular resource, so a logged-in publisher could go to his profile using the /publisher route.

My routes file has the following

```
resources :publishers, :only => [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
resource :publisher, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
```

And in my view controller I have the link

```
<li><%= link_to "View General Settings", publishers_path(@publisher) %></li>
```

**The problem: the links is translated to URL `/publisher.1` (instead of `publisher/1`)**

(`.1` represents `publisher_id`; when the `publisher_id` is 2, it renders to `/publisher.2`)

**Any suggestions as to why this happens, and how to fix it?**

I post here my routes:

```
    publishers GET /publishers(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"publishers"}
edit_publisher GET /publishers/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"publishers"}
     publisher GET  /publishers/:id(.:format)     {:action=>"show", :controller=>"publishers"}
               PUT  /publishers/:id(.:format)     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"publishers"}
               POST /publisher(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"publishers"}
 new_publisher GET  /publisher/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"publishers"}
               GET  /publisher/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"publishers"}
               GET  /publisher(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"publishers"}
               PUT  /publisher(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"publishers"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as Tyler said, you're using the publishers resource routes as opposed to publisher ones.

Since this is going to cause confusion in the future, I'd suggest removing the singular resource publisher and matching the named route to the show action of the publishers controller, like this:

```
match "/publisher/:id" => "publishers#show"
```

Also, if you don't want to have the ID part in the named route, you can remove it, but then you'll have to come up with a way of storing the ID of a publisher in some way. A session variable comes to mind.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, works Well! However, the reason I went through all this trouble is that I want to hide the publisher ID from the URLs (I don't want publishers to know their IDs). Is there a smart way for me to do so?

Comment: When they log in as a user, grab the associated publisher ID and store it in a session. Use that instead of params[:id] for the show action.

Answer (score 1):

Try using publisher_path rather than publishers_path?